# How do I find the current route from a decorator?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to write a decorator that will sit on a `<ul>` element and apply an "active" class to its children `<li>` based on the current route that is active.

Is it possible for me to inject the router into the decorator and do something like the following?

```dart
class ActiveNavDecorator {

  RouteProvider _router;
  String _currentRoute;

  ActiveNavDecorator(this._router) {
    _currentRoute = _router.currentURLPath() // I am looking for something that will do this
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Thanks,
Jarred

Comment: What doesn't work? Didn't you just try it?

Comment: currentURLPath() is not a real method. It is just showing what I want to accomplish.

Comment: But you get a RouteProvider instance injected?

Comment: Again, I am demonstrating what I want to do. This code is not functional.

Comment: Again, do you get the RouteProvider instance injected? ;-) I assume you have tried?

Comment: Actually, it looks like _router is null. I am assuming this is because the decorator is applied outside of ng-view?

Comment: I didn't use Angular for quite a while therefore I can't provide very detailed info. I would expect that when your `ng-app` is `body` this should work everywhere in the DOM (at least outside of a shadowDOM).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for this problem.

> I can only take partial credit, because I researched this a couple months ago and came across a similar solution that I based my solution on. I can't remember who wrote that original solution or where I read it, so… apologies in advance! If the original author sees this and leaves a comment, I will update my answer with an attribution.

Anyway, the first part is a decorator:

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:route_hierarchical/client.dart';

/// This decorator modifies UI elements based on the currently selected route.
///
/// For example, when a menu item is clicked, we add an 'active' CSS class
/// to that element so that the user can see where they are.
@Decorator(selector: '[current-route]')
class CurrentRoute {
    Router router;
    Element element;

    /// Constructor.
    ///
    /// Takes an HTML [element] to monitor and the application's [router]. The
    /// element must contain a child <a> element. When the route changes, the
    /// anchor href's first path component will be compared to the new route's
    /// first path component. If it matches, the CSS class `active` will be
    /// added to the element. If the route does not match, then the CSS class
    /// `active` will be removed.
    CurrentRoute(Element element, Router router) {
        this.element = element;
        this.router = router;

        toggleActive(window.location.href);

        router.onRouteStart.listen((e) {
            toggleActive(e.uri);
        });
    }

    /// Returns true if the given URI matches the anchor href for this element.
    bool isRoute(String uri) {
        Element anchor;

        if (this.element is AnchorElement) {
            anchor = this.element;
        } else {
            anchor = this.element.querySelector('a');
        }

        String anchorPath = anchor.pathname.split('/')[1];
        String routePath = Uri.parse(uri).path.split('/')[1];

        return anchorPath == routePath;
    }

    /// Set the `active` CSS class on an element when it matches the currently
    /// selected route.
    void toggleActive(String uri) {
        if (isRoute(uri)) {
            element.classes.add('active');
        } else {
            element.classes.remove('active');
        }
    }
}
```

The basic mechanism is that every time a new route starts, each element that is decorated with `current-route` will run the `isRoute()` logic, which checks to see if the first path component of the current `window.location` is equal to the first path component of the anchor's `href`. (E.g. the `window.location` is /foo/bar/baz and the anchor's `href` is `/foo`, then that's a match.)

> There are other possible ways to perform this step, of course, and you should customize `isRoute()` as needed for your use case. This just happened to work well for my use case.

Next, you need to register `CurrentRoute` with Angular's DI. That's left as an exercise for the reader.

Finally, here's an example of the markup to use it, based on a Bootstrap style nav:

```
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
  <li current-route>
    <a href='/foo'>Foo</a>
  </li>
  <li current-route>
    <a href='/bar'>Bar</a>
  </li>
  <li current-route>
    <a href='/baz'>Baz</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that the decorator is applied on the element that needs the `active` class. The decorator will search for the first `<a>` child of that element if the element is not itself an anchor.